# Call scroll event after calling Longpress using GestureDetector

Tags: android, scroll, long-press, gesturedetector

How should I call a scroll event after calling Longpress without release a screen (using gesturedetector)?

Here is my class:

```
public class TestingGestureDetector extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    TextView mTextView;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing_gesture_detector);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gesture);
        mTextView.setOnTouchListener(a());
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);          //


    }


    protected View.OnTouchListener a() {
        return new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);           //

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    mTextView.setText("Release");
                return true;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        mTextView.setText("Press");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        mTextView.setText("Move");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {

        mTextView.setText("Long Press");
        //mGestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Disable the longpress using setIsLongpressEnabled(isLongpressEnabled)
  on your gestureDetector.
- Check the state of some pressed flag after 0.5s using a timer or
  thread.

Try:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)== true)
        {
            //Fling or other gesture detected (not logpress because it is disabled)
        }
        else
        {
            //Manually handle the event.
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                //Remember the time and press position
                Log.e("test","Action down");
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                //Check if user is actually longpressing, not slow-moving 
                // if current position differs much then press positon then discard whole thing
                // If position change is minimal then after 0.5s that is a longpress. You can now process your other gestures 
                Log.e("test","Action move");
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                //Get the time and position and check what that was :)
                Log.e("test","Action down");
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
```